# Getting a value from an inner array from Document MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I'm using the JAVA Driver and am performing a document find.
The returned documents are of type Document.

From the code I can see the String type('name') which comes out correctly.
I can also see the hours array as a string.

What i am looking to do is get a specific element from the array that is to pick out hours[1][2] which would be value 8.

Im trying to do this operation straight on the Document type without converting to a JSONObject.

Is this possible ?

> {
>   "name": "Temp1",    "hours": [
>        [
>          0,
>          1,
>          2,
>          3,
>          4,
>          5
>        ],
>          [
>          6,
>          7,
>          8,
>          9,
>          10,
>          11
>        ],[
>          12,
>          13,
>          14,
>          15,
>          16,
>          17
>        ] ]
>           {

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find(and(eq("day", day),eq("month", month),eq("year", year),eq("name", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("Temp"))));         
iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            //System.out.println(document.toJson());
            System.out.println("Name: "+document.getString("name"));                    
            System.out.println("Hours[]: "+document.get("hours"));
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it to a DBList object such as :

```
(BasicDBList) document.get("hours");
```

You can then iterate over the list just as normal list !

Comment: Hi in driver 3.0.2 im not seeing a type DBList only BasicDBList. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Your example gives me a cast exception. However a (java.util.ArrayList) document.get("hours"); does work.

Comment: cast List<Document> instead of BasicDBList